# Avoid generating empty STDOUT and STDERR files with Sun Grid Engine (SGE) and array jobs

Tags: stdout, stderr, sungridengine

I am running array jobs with Sun Grid Engine (SGE).

My carefully scripted array job workers generate no stdout and no stderr when they function properly. Unfortunately, SGE insists on creating an empty stdout and stderr file for each run.

Sun's manual states:

```
              STDOUT  and  STDERR of array job tasks will be written into dif-
              ferent files with the default location

              .['e'|'o']'.'

              In order to change this default, the  -e  and  -o  options  (see
              above)  can  be  used together with the pseudo-environment-vari-
              ables  $HOME,  $USER,   $JOB_ID,   $JOB_NAME,   $HOSTNAME,   and
              $SGE_TASK_ID.

              Note, that you can use the output redirection to divert the out-
              put of all tasks into the same file, but the result of  this  is
              undefined.
```

I would like to have the output files suppressed if they are empty. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: all I could do was cry